# Using nest and purrr::map outside of mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

Lets say I want to split out mtcars into 3 csv files based on their cyl grouping. I can use mutate to do this, but it will create a `NULL` column in the output.

```
library(tidyverse)
by_cyl = mtcars %>% 
           group_by(cyl) %>%
           nest()
by_cyl %>%
  mutate(unused = map2(data, cyl, function(x, y) write.csv(x, paste0(y, '.csv'))))
```

is there a way to do this on the by_cyl object without calling mutate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option using `purrr` without `mutate` from `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  walk2(names(.), ~write_csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv')))
```

#### Update

This drops the `cyl` column before saving the output.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% select(-cyl)) %>%
  walk2(names(.), ~write_csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv')))
```

#### Update2

```
library(tidyverse)
by_cyl <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()
by_cyl %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  walk2(names(.), ~write_csv(.x[["data"]][[1]], paste0(.y, '.csv')))
```

Comment: How would I do this if my data is grouped and nested? should I unnest, and then split?

Comment: @kmace Please see my update. We can drop the `cyl` column before saving the CSV.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clearer. my tibble has many columns that are nested data.frames. so your method would work, but Ill need to select out the column I want, unnest it, and then pipe it through split etc.

Comment: @kmace Please see my update again. We can use the index to access the content stored in the `data` column when storing the CSV.

Comment: Your answer is great. I ended up slightly modifying it, using `pull` instead of indexing. I basically replace the last line of Update2 with: `walk(~ write.csv(.x %>% pull(data) %>% as.data.frame, paste0(.x %>% pull(cyl), '.csv')))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `do` and `group_by`, so if your data is already grouped as it should, you save one line:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(write.csv(.,paste0(.$cyl[1],".csv"))))
```

`data.frame` is only used here because `do` needs to return a `data.frame`, so it's a little hack.

Comment: that was the original error I was running into. Hadley has said that `purrr::map` will eventually replace the `do` function so I was trying to do it with `purrr`

Comment: Yes actually with `imap` you can probably do it. I cannot test but last line would be something like `imap(write.csv(.x,paste0(.y,".csv")))`